# Why Will Xcode 9.2 beta not Download?

Tags: xcode, apple-id, developer-program

Xcode 9.2 beta (9C30) was released today, but I have been unable to download it from developer.apple.com. I am using a non-paid Apple ID, but this hasn't caused trouble for Xcode downloads in the past. When I click the blue "Download" button next to the latest Xcode beta, I am presented with a "403 Forbidden" error.

I've tried using Chrome, signing out of my Developer ID, and clearing cookies/cache for apple.com, but nothing has worked. Has anybody else had this issue or know how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably Apple, not you.

Comment: I would think it is, but I'm just confused, as this had never happened before (at least in my experience). I've already filed a bug report for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple seems to have resolved this issue.